# VB.net Random number generator is repeating the same value

Tags: vb.net, sorting, random

I am trying to create an array of random values so that I can bubble sort them. The problem is, the random number generator is not working and repeats the same number over and over. I've used this method of random number generating before and its worked just fine. If I put a breakpoint into the code in the CreateArray() loop, then it works just fine, but I have to step through the code manually. I can't understand how it works with a breakpoint, but doesn't work without one.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Value_Array As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim No_Of_Items As Integer = 10
    Dim Pass_No As Integer = 1
    Dim Temp As Integer
    Value_Array = CreateArray(No_Of_Items)
    For Pass_No = 1 To (No_Of_Items - 1)
        For j = 0 To (No_Of_Items - (Pass_No + 1))
            If Value_Array(j) > Value_Array(j + 1) Then
                Temp = Value_Array(j)
                Value_Array(j) = Value_Array(j + 1)
                Value_Array(j + 1) = Temp
            End If
        Next
    Next
    For i = 0 To (No_Of_Items - 1)
        Console.Write(Value_Array(i) & ", ")
    Next
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
Function GenerateRandomNumber()
    Dim Random_Number As Random = New Random()
    Dim Random As Integer = Random_Number.Next(0, 101)
    Return Random
End Function
Function CreateArray(No_Of_Items)
    Dim Count As Integer = 0
    Dim Temp_Array As New List(Of Integer)
    Do Until Count = No_Of_Items
        Temp_Array.Add(GenerateRandomNumber())
        Count = Count + 1
    Loop
    Return Temp_Array
End Function
```

Comment: Do not create `New Random` every time, create it once and reuse in all executions of `GenerateRandomNumber`

Comment: `Initializing two random number generators in a tight loop or in rapid succession creates two random number generators that can produce identical sequences of random numbers. [...] Both to improve performance and to avoid inadvertently creating separate random number generators that generate identical numeric sequences, we recommend that you create one Random object to generate many random numbers over time, instead of creating new Random objects to generate one random number.` [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not create New Random every time, create it once and reuse in all executions of GenerateRandomNumber.
`New Random()` will use current time as a seed for generated random numbers. Instances of `Random` created with same seed will generate same random numbers.
Loops executes very fast, so every time you create new instance of `Random` it will use same time seed and all instances will generate same numbers.

You can use `Static` declaration for using only one instance for all executions of the method

```
Function GenerateRandomNumber() As Integer
    Static Random_Number As New Random()
    Return Random_Number.Next(0, 101)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always create the `Random` instance in the method `GenerateRandomNumber` with the [default constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9(v=vs.110).aspx) it will use the current time as seed. If you call that method very fast, f.e. in a loop, you will always generate the same numbers.

Instead (1) store the `Random` instance somewhere, for example in a field, or (2) pass it as argument to the method.

This all is also mentioned in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The default seed value is derived from the **system clock** and has finite
>   resolution. As a result, different Random objects that are **created in
>   close succession by a call to the default constructor will have
>   identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical
>   sets of random numbers**. This problem can be avoided by using a single
>   `Random` object to generate all random numbers. You can also work around
>   it by modifying the seed value returned by the system clock and then
>   explicitly providing this new seed value to the `Random(Int32)`
>   constructor.

So here is option 2 as example:

```
Function GenerateRandomNumber(random As Random) As Int32
    Dim randomNumber As Integer = random.Next(0, 101)
    Return randomNumber
End Function
```

....

```
Dim rnd As New Random()

Do Until Count = No_Of_Items
    Temp_Array.Add(GenerateRandomNumber(rnd))
    Count = Count + 1
Loop
```